# Is there a maximum slug length?

Tags: slug

A client just created a post with a really long slug (90 characters), no special characters (other than hyphens) etc.

Whenever the link to that post was clicked, including the "Preview" or "View this Post" links from the Admin back end, a 404 was generated.

Once we manually trimmed the slug, everything worked as expected. Is this a "feature" or a "bug"?

EDIT: a Note for all those talking about DB limits.

> If I were hitting the DB field limit, then the slug itself would be
>   truncated. Think about it for a second. In the case of most WP
>   installations, wp_posts.post_name is VARCHAR(200). So, let's say that
>   someone types in a title with > 200 chars. What happens? The slug gets
>   truncated to 200 chars and stored in wp_posts.post_name. It's not like
>   someone is going in and typing the full title of the post in the
>   browser address bar, substituting the spaces with dashes right? The
>   URL is being generated by WordPress, and it's getting the URL from the
>   wp_posts.post_name table and just putting that in the href attribute
>   of the anchor tag. So there's not going to be a disparity there. The
>   whole DB thing is a red herring.

In any case, the slug in question is only 90 chars, so it has nothing to do with DB limits.

Are there any known limitations around rewrite?

Comment: You can use a free tool like MySQL workbench to check the datatype (and maximum length if any) of any wordpress field as defined in the corresponding wordpress table/column

Answer (score 11):

Due to wp_posts table structure the length of post_name column (the column for slugs) is equal to 200 characters.

Comment: @TomAuger & Eugene - can you confirm the issue, because Tom says the slug had 90 chars. I'm aware that the limit is 200, but this doesn't counts the home URL, does it?

Comment: @Eugene, exactly. 200 characters. My slug was exactly 90 chars, so we're not hitting the DB limit.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it doesnt have a limit by it self but the property of the field in the database for slugs might be set to a max length.

So check the Database!

Comment: @The one who downvoted: The answer is _correct_. Therefore I reupvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem wasn't even directly WordPress/database related at all ...

But the length of the URL exceeded 255 characters (and not all web-browser do like that).

What happened here might have been an URL longer than 255 chars, which got truncated by the browser's address-bar when opening it ... causing the retrieval of a bad permalink ... which resulted in a 4o4.

So assumable the maximum slug-length might be:

255 - the length of (Protocol + FQDN + permalink structure) ...

- based on a browser's hard limit.

But it cannot be longer than 200 chars ...

- based on the post_name's field size.

Even if somethings else might have caused the 4o4 in this particular case.

It could have been a character which wasn't properly url_encoded as well,
reasons for 4o4's are quite endless ... ever considered a bad cluster on HDD or a faulty RAM module? :)

Comment: The GUID is not the URL. It just happens to look like one, but is not used to read a request. If you move WordPress from one domain to another the GUID will not be changed. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6492 and http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10857.

Comment: Erm, for what else than identification purposes should a unique ID be used then? I mean, the question basically is: What's the reason a 4o4 is thrown in this case?

Comment: The 404 and the GUID are not related, I think. WordPress just doesn't use the GUID when it searches for a post that matches an URL.

Comment: Think you're right on that... post_name and GUID can be excluded as source of the problem - what's left are permalinks and re-writes. Without Apache logfiles or anything this is just guessing around ;)

Comment: @syslogic I think rewrites is probably the cause and bears further investigation. The URL, including the http:// part was still under 128 chars, so I don't think it's hitting a hard browser limit on URL length.

Comment: @TomAuger if it's that short, my conclusion might not apply - just wanted to point out that possibility as well. Apparently this question cannot be answered without FTP/mySQL access.