# Why is my WordPress URL shortened

Tags: urls

My WordPress settings are to have the post title in the URL separated by hyphens. However, if the WordPress post title is too long, it will not display the whole title in the URL?

I have double checked the WP settings and cannot see any issues in how it is set up.

How can I restore the URLs to be full length, word for word, as the post titles?

Comment: Are you running any SEO plugins?

Comment: It's not good to have too long Titles and URL's because of SEO reasons. Keep title and URL under 80 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Due to wp_posts table structure the length of post_name column (the column for slugs) is equal to 200 characters.
- Source - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53044/15360