# Permalink length

Tags: permalinks

I use Bengali font/language on my site. And its old blog.
Now the issue is, my post permalink are this:
website.com/blog-post-name

As I use benglai, the permalink are looks like this: 
website.com/blog-post-n

Thats mean part of the name are broken. I know there have some limits on permalink like how many character can be there. As its unicode font, word are more then its limit.

So wanna know how can I increase the limits as its looks really bad with broken permalink.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53042/is-there-a-maximum-slug-length

Comment: Also https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10483